# Cat adjustment period when starting Zonisamide

Tags: diseases, new-medicine

I recently started my cat, Claude, on Zonisamide for epilepsy, and I'm curious about your experiences.

How long did it take for your cats to adjust to taking Zonisamide, and did you notice any specific changes or side effects during this adjustment period?

Claude seems to be having a very hard time.  He is very sedate and is have major coordination issues when trying to walk. Thank you!

Comment: If concerned, ask your vet whether this is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with humans, medication side-effects with animals should be reported to a doctor (veterinarian) right away. You can *additionally* contact the medication's manufacturer. If your government has a regulating body to which you can report animal medication side-effects, you may want to report the side-effects to them as well.

We wish Claude the best!